# Revel payment for Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

In my Xamarin forms application, I need to integrate Revel Payment gateway. Does revel payment supports Xamarin platform?

http://revelsystems.com/

Comment: I think this question is better suited to be asked at Revel themselves is it not? It's a pretty broad question with no real programming problem being presented so it's not quite suited for SO. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a lot of information about this, and Revel's website doesn't explicitly mention any access to API's or SDK's that might allow you to do this. The only thing i came across is a company called Apiant ([Website here](https://apiant.com/connect/Revel-Systems-to-Xamarin-Unified)) that apparently offer consultations on how to create workflows that link xamarin unified and revel systems. That said though I couldn't find any information on how you would do this yourself.

I suspect this is a question best suited for 'RevelSystems' and not the wider community of stackoverflow.